# Linear Transformation of Dirichlet Distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, multinomial, log-likelihood, dirichlet

I am wondering what is the best way to represent the probability distribution of a linearly transformed Dirichlet distribution:

let {X = [x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub> ... x<sub>n</sub>] | Σx<sub>i</sub> = 1} be a set of multinomial probabilities that follow a Dirichlet distribution D<sub>ɑ<sub>n</sub></sub>.

Consider matrix A<sub>nxm</sub> where: 
A<sub>nxm</sub>X = Y st. (Σy<sub>i</sub> = 1 ∀X) *(Note A<sub>nxm</sub> is derived from a Bayesian net)*

**If X follows a Derichlet Distribution what distribution does Y follow?!?**

If believe that if A<sub>nxm</sub> is an invertible square matrix. By A<sub>nxm</sub>X being injective and surjective, Y follows the below distribution: 
Likelihood(Y) = D<sub>ɑ<sub>n</sub></sub>(A<sup>-1</sup>Y)

But I am not sure what to do for other cases.
Thank you!

this paper may be useful but it is beyond me... 
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.2307/3315988